# How to force Antd to append element as child element of div React renders to instead of to HTML body?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, antd

### Edit:

I figured it out & posted answer below.

---

### Original Question

I am trying to create a completely compartmentalized web application within a shadow-dom and I've been using Antd components and ran into the issue where Antd is appending drop-down options into the body tag instead of as a child of the element that React is rendering into.

To isolate this issue I've removed everything outside of just React.render & a single Antd element which still does the same thing.

I then used a different component, "react-date-picker", which works how I had hoped Antd did, where the component renders as a child of the div specified for react.

Unfortunately, Antd rendering to the body of the HTML instead of as a child makes using shadow-root pointless.

Essentially my question is:

Is this Antd's normal functionality? If not then what might I be screwing up to have this happen? If so then is there a built-in Antd option that I'm missing that will render Antd options as child elements? If that option doesn't exist within their libraries, is there a way for me to force Antd to render as a child of my shadow-root node?

Here is what I'm using to render the Antd DatePicker component:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'antd/lib/date-picker';
ReactDOM.render(<DatePicker/>, document.getElementById('entry-fields'));
```

Before clicking on the Antd date picker:
[image: before antd date-picker clicked]

After clicking on it, drop down options are appended to `<body>` and not `<div id="entry-fields>`:
[image: after antd date-picker clicked]

Here is what I'm using to render the react-date-picker component to demonstrate the functionality I expected / need:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
class Example extends React.Component {
    state = {
        startDate: new Date()
    };

    handleChange = (date: any) => {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <DatePicker
                selected={this.state.startDate}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('entry-fields'));
```

Before clicking on the react-date-picker date picker:
[image: before react-date-picker clicked]

After clicking on the react-date-picker date picker (the drop down options are appended as children of the element react is rendered onto):
[image: after react-date-picker clicked]

Basically I expected Antd to render its options encapsulated within the React rendered into `<div></div>` but it is instead appending elements on the `<body></body>`.

I'm relatively inexperienced in the web-dev domain and have resorted to asking a question here after way too much time trying to find the answer on my own. I am getting extremely frustrated in web-dev in general where any question seems to yield hundreds of irrelevant medium blog posts that are not useful in any capacity... assuming that it's not just me not knowing what to search for yet to find the answers I need which could very well be the case.

Really appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: By looking at:

https://ant.design/components/date-picker/

i can see a property called getCalendarContainer.
have you tried messing with that?

Comment: please add you own answer and accept it since you found the solution, might help others in the future :)

Comment: Will do. It apparently says I need to wait 2 days so I'll check back then. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how I managed to miss this but Antd has a parameter called "getCalendarContainer" which if left blank will render options into the body of the document but if supplied with the correct parameters will render the child elements into the container of your choosing.

Going off this example: https://react-component.github.io/calendar/examples/getCalendarContainer.html

I got it working by adding this function to my component:

```
getCalendarContainer() 
{
    return this.d || document.getElementById('calendarContainer');
}
```

and adding this to the component in JSX:

```
<div id="calendarContainer"  ref={n => (this.d = n as HTMLDivElement)} >
    <DatePicker onChange={EntryFields.onDateChange} getCalendarContainer={this.getCalendarContainer}/>
</div>
```

and initializing the div tag to reference it in the component's constructor like this:

```
private d: HTMLDivElement;
constructor(props: any)
{
    super(props);
    this.d = document.createElement("div");
...
```

It's also worth noting that the above will not work immediately when using shadow-DOM since you need to access the node that the shadow-DOM is a child to and then use getElementById().

Something along these lines (but probably better written I hope lol)

```
    getContainer() {
        let elem = null;
        let shadowContainer = document.getElementById('entryFieldsShadow')  as HTMLInputElement;
        if (shadowContainer != null) {
            let shadowDom = shadowContainer.firstElementChild;
            if (shadowDom != null) {
                let shadowRoot = shadowDom.shadowRoot;
                if (shadowRoot != null) {
                    elem = shadowRoot.getElementById("entryFieldsContainer")
                }
            }
        }
        return elem || this.d;
    }
```

where the JSX with react-shadow's shadow root is included looks like this:

```
return (
            <div id="entryFieldsShadow">
                <root.div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="entryFieldsContainer"/>
                        <style type="text/css"> @import "static/1.css"; </style>
                        <Layout>
                            <Content>
                                {this.RowCols()}
                            </Content>
                        </Layout>
                    </div>
                </root.div>
            </div>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problems

```js
<DatePicker
  {...}
  getCalendarContainer={triggerNode => triggerNode.parentNode}
/>
```